# NLA editor issue. Whenever I move another object, the character goes crazy

Tags: nla-editor

Multiple people have been facing this problem like Janae Dotson.

My situation is that I have a running animation for a character. I turned this into an action and pushed it down in the NLA editor I also combined this action (interpolation for both actions is combine) with another action that made the character move in a horizontal direction.

My problem is that whenever I move another object the character goes crazy and is flying 10ft above where it is supposed to be. By moving another object I mean pressing crtl alt zero to position my camera.

An important detail is that the character does its running animation but it just does it in the wrong place and is upside down.

Janae's question is the 3rd question for the tag nla

[image: Here is the character correctly atop the hill]

[image: The character moves away when the camera position is changed]

[image: This is where the character is now, in a random place above where is it is supposed to be]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C8aC1AKvSa170UYaL-O_EuDn6UM-W8fq/view Here is the link to the file.

Comment: Thanks for improving the title susu. My bad.

Comment: hello, maybe share your file (at least the important elements): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots thanks for suggesting improvements :) Just a suggestion though, many newcomers don't realize to make edits, it would be useful to guide them someway. :)

Comment: you mean how to put their file in the original post?

Comment: @moonboots hey :) Yeah, alot of new users don't realize to and so comments end up with the info... using the magic `[edit]` link works :)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C8aC1AKvSa170UYaL-O_EuDn6UM-W8fq/view?usp=sharing